# Multivalued Histogram as combined scatter and histogram plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gnuplot, histogram

I have some theoretical calculations for something in my research. I want to represent the accuracy of this data by taking the theoretical values and subtracting them from the experimental values. This leaves some difference that I would like to plot to display this data.

I have made a mock representation of the type of plot I'm looking for. The red line is the zero of the plot, meaning no difference between the theoretical and experimental values. The x-axis has V1, V2, ..., VN which are different things to be calculated. The problem is that each V has between two or three values, represented by the "X" in the mock figure I made.

[image: example picture showing the problem]

I'm a bit lost on how to do this. I tried looking at Multivalued histograms with Gnuplot, though it turned up empty. Can anyone give any insight on this, or have a working example Gnuplot script? I'm open to using other ideas too if you know a way to do this in Python or some other way. The problem is I know nothing about Python.

Comment: Sorry, not very clear to me, can you describe in more detail how you'd like your final figure to look? Plotting multiple lines of points, plotting with histogram-like stepped lines, stacking histograms, multiple non-overlapping histograms... all possible.

Answer (score 3):

Using gnuplot there are several ways to achieve this. Here is one option, which I find quite reasonable::

1. Store the values belonging to one `v`-value in one data block. Two data blocks are separated with *two* new lines from each other. So an example data file might be:

   ```
   # v1 values
   -0.5
   1.1
   0.4
   -0.2


   # v2 values
   -0.1
   0.1
   -0.7


   # v3 values 
   0.9 
   0.5
   0.2
   ```
2. The labels are stored in a string, separated by space characters. (With this you can only use labels which don't contain spaces themselves, quoting doesn't work).

   ```
   labels = "v1 v2 v3"
   ```
3. As numerical value for the x-axis you can take the number of the data block, which you get with the special column `-2`, i.e. with `using (column(-2))`. This number can also be used to access the respective label from the `labels` string.

Here is an example script:

```
set xzeroaxis lc rgb 'red' lt 1 lw 2
set offset 0.2,0.2,0,0
set xtics 1
unset key
set linetype 1 linetype 2 lc rgb 'black' lw 2
labels = "v1 v2 v3"
plot 'data.dat' using (column(-2)):1:xtic(word(labels, column(-2)+1))
```

The result with 4.6.5 is:

[image]

Of course you have a lot of options to modify or extend this script, depending on your actual needs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be counting anything, so your plot isn't a histogram.  It's a bunch of vertical 1D scatter plots arranged horizontally.

The following uses matplotlib to get pretty close to your mock up (out of habit, I renamed "Differences" to the fairly conventional term "Residuals"):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


np.random.seed(123)

# Demo data consists of a list of names of the "variables",
# and a list of the residuals (in numpy arrays) for each variable.
names = ['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4']

r1 = np.random.randn(3)
r2 = np.random.randn(2)
r3 = np.random.randn(3)
r4 = np.random.randn(3)
residuals = [r1, r2, r3, r4]

# Make the plot

for k, (name, res) in enumerate(zip(names, residuals)):
    plt.plot(np.zeros_like(res) + k, res, 'kx',
             markersize=7.0, markeredgewidth=2)

plt.ylabel("Residuals", fontsize=14)
plt.xlim(-1, len(names))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(range(len(names)))
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.axhline(0, color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot residuals]